# How to edit primary keys from shp2pgsql-gui output?

Tags: postgis, shp2pgsql

I have a newbie question. I am importing multiple shapefiles into `shp2pgsql-gui` and creating a `postgis` database. While creating the database, `shp2pgsql` adds a new `gid` column for each layer that becomes the new primary key. I do not need this column and want the `id` field for each layer in the original shapefile to also serve as the primary key. I tried connecting to the new database (created from `shp2pgsql`) using `pgAdmin` but find that I am unable to change the primary key from `gid` to the `id` field within pgAdmin. Any suggestions on how this might be possible?

Comment: Try gist.github.com/scaryguy/6269293. Be aware that it may be hard to add new features into that sort of PostGIS table with generic GIS software like QGIS because they do not know what to use as a new FID. With FID that is of type "integer autoincrement" that is not a problem. I would consider an alternative to let shp2pgsql do what it does and add a UNIQUE constraint into your id field.

Answer (score 2):

Going with the `shp2pgsql` output as is and adding a `UNIQUE` constraint is exactly what I ended up doing as well! It works nicely.